# Does IIS 7.5 server farm need to be on a Domain? 2008 R

Tags: web-farm

We are using Server 2008 R IIS 7.5 with an SQL DB on the backend. At the moment the system is working fine with three of the servers configured in a load balancing farm while communicating data back to the SQL DB. All of these servers are free standing on their own subnet with a common admin and password. The question is… is there an advantage for making one server a PDC and creating their own domain and joining the rest of the remember servers to the domain?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this when setting up a similar web farm and all of the resources I queried said that for security reasons you should definitely not join web servers in a DMZ with a domain on a private network.

Most resources also suggested that it wasn't a great idea to create a separate domain in your DMZ for the web servers.

So I opted to do the same thing and just have stand alone servers that share admin username and password and I've been running them for over a year and have no regrets about my decision.